# React Material Table action button markup overriding for multiple actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-table

Action overriding feature allows me to override button but it overrides all the action buttons. For example, if I have two action buttons for edit and delete and I use the Action overriding, both of my buttons get overridden with that same custom code.
How can I specify different codes for different buttons?

My final goal is to conditionally disable edit and delete buttons based on the rowData. I have tried with isEditable feature as shown in the code below but it doesn't work either.

```
  ...
  ....
  const components = {
       Action: props => (
           <IconButton aria-label="delete" size="small"
               disabled={props.data.email === 'admin@pipilika.com'}
               onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)}
               >
               <Icon>delete</Icon>
           </IconButton>
       )

   };

   const actions = [
       {
           icon: 'edit',
           tooltip: 'Edit Index',
           onClick: (event, rowData) => {
               this.onEditClick(null, rowData._id);
           }
       },
       {
           icon: 'delete',
           tooltip: 'Delete Index',
           onClick: (event, rowData) => {
               this.onDeleteClick(null, rowData._id);
           }
       },
   ];


    const options= {
        showTitle: false,
        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        searchFieldStyle: {
            color: "#fff"
        }
    };

    const editable= {
        isEditable: rowData => rowData.dataType === "html", 
        isDeletable: rowData => rowData.dataType === "html", 
    };

    return(
        <MaterialTable
            editable={editable}
            title="Created Index List"
            columns={columns}
            data={dataTypes}
            actions={actions}
            options={options}
            components={components}
            style={{overflow: 'hidden'}}
        />
    );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for this specific use case, you can choose which Button to render based on checking the right icon name like this.

```
      components={{
        Action: 
            props => {
                    if(props.action.icon === 'edit'){
                        return(
                        <Button
                        onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)}
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        style={{textTransform: 'none'}}
                        size="small"
                        disabled
                        >
                        My Button 
                        </Button>
                        )
                    }
                    if(props.action.icon === 'save'){
                        return(
                            <Button
                            onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)}
                            color="primary"
                            variant="contained"
                            style={{textTransform: 'none'}}
                            size="small"
                            >
                            My Button 
                            </Button>
                        )
                    }
                }

      }}
```

Comment: then how can I use material-ui select with the triple dot in action and on every option there is different option function called?

Comment: How can I get the data of the row selected? your example works when you want change the component for a specific icon, but if you want to render a button according to specific conditions, What about that?

Answer (score 6):

This solution worded form me:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core/';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

class ButtonBack extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            onClick: props.onClick,
            icon: props.icon
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Button label="Regresar" onClick={this.state.onClick}>
                <Icon>{this.state.icon}</Icon>
                Regresar
            </Button>
        );
    }
}

export default ButtonBack;






 components={{
            Action: props => {


                if (typeof props.action === "function"){
                    var element= props.action(props.data);
                    return (
                        <IconButton aria-label={element.icon} size="small"
                            onClick={element.onClick}
                        >
                            <Icon>{element.icon}</Icon>
                        </IconButton>
                        )
                }else{
                    if (props.action.icon==="keyboard_backspace"){
                        return (
                            <ButtonBack icon={props.action.icon} 
                                onClick={props.action.onClick}
                            >
                            </ButtonBack>
                            )
                    }else{
                        return (
                            <IconButton aria-label={props.action.icon} size="small"
                                onClick={props.action.onClick}
                            >
                                <Icon>{props.action.icon}</Icon>
                            </IconButton>
                            )
                    }


                }   
            }
 }}
```