# React Material Table action OnClick event for edit and delete does not fire action

Tags: reactjs, material-table

In order to disable some action only for some rows I'm trying to overwrite the Action for each row. I followed the answer given here: [React Material Table action button markup overriding for multiple actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777516/react-material-table-action-button-markup-overriding-for-multiple-actions)

```
Action:
    props => {

      if (typeof props.action === "function"){
            var element= props.action(props.data);
      

            return (
                <Button aria-label={element.icon} size="small"
                    onClick={element.onClick}
                >
                <element.icon/>
                </Button>
                )
        }else{

                return (
                    <Button aria-label={props.action.icon} size="small"
                        onClick={props.action.onClick}
                    >
                        <props.action.icon/>
                    </Button>
                    )



        }
        }

  }}
```

Everything works well for the action add. A new row within a form is displayed for the add button (the else part of the action). But Nothing is fired for the typeof props.action === "function". There is no error and element.onClick is a onClick function. I tried also

```
onClick={e => element.onClick}
```

But it doesn't fire nothin neither.

Any clues or ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using:
`onClick{(event) => element.onClick(event, props.yourData)}`

Passing props with the function is a necessity here.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

I had to to this:

```
onClick={(event) => element.onClick(event, props.data)}
```

instead of

```
onClick={element.onClick}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assign **this** to some variable before rendering it to the onClick function. ex see below define **var assiigned_this**.
Then call a function in the following way. Here the assiigned_this is nothing but **this** and second argument you can pass anything which you need. Here I am passing number 4.

```
renderRows() {
    var assigned_this = this;
    return (
      <tr key={"item-" + i}>
        <td>
          <button onClick={assigned_this.handleItemOnClick.bind(assigned_this, 4)}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
```

Now define the click function in the following way.

```
handleItemOnClick(i) {
   console.log(i)  // It will print 4
  }
```

Now on click of the handleItemOnClick function, you can see the result in the console.